# Unable to access jarfile ..\framework\monkeyrunner-25.3.2.jar

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Executing a monkeyrunner command from windows command prompt(Admin) returns an error saying that

> Unable to access jarfile ..\framework\monkeyrunner-25.3.2.jar

Here is the command I have executed

```
monkeyrunner -help text Help
```

And I could find this jar under \Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib path.

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered the same problem. There are some errors in the bat file ***monkeyrunner.bat*** for command prompt users.
Fix it in 26 seconds:

1. Creating a file ***mymonkeyrunner.bat*** in the directory which contains ***monkeyrunner.bat***.
2. Copy the code below to ***mymonkeyrunner.bat***.

   ```
   @echo off
   rem Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
   rem
   rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
   rem
   rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
   rem
   rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   rem limitations under the License.

   rem don't modify the caller's environment
   setlocal

   rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
   rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
   set prog=%~f0

   rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
   rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
   cd /d %~dp0

   rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
   set java_exe=
   call ..\lib\find_java.bat
   if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
   for /f %%a in ("%APP_HOME%\lib\monkeyrunner-25.3.2.jar") do set jarfile=%%~nxa
   set frameworkdir=.
   set libdir=

   if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
       set frameworkdir=..\lib

   if exist %frameworkdir%\%jarfile% goto JarFileOk
       set frameworkdir=..\framework

   :JarFileOk

   set jarpath=%frameworkdir%\%jarfile%

   if not defined ANDROID_SWT goto QueryArch
       set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%
       goto SwtDone

   :QueryArch

       for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%frameworkdir%\..\bin\archquery') do set swt_path=%frameworkdir%\%%a

   :SwtDone

   if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
       echo SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
       echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
       exit /B

   :SetPath

   call "%java_exe%" -Xmx512m "-Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir%;%swt_path%" -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir=..\..\platform-tools -jar %jarpath% %*
   ```